# Microsoft Word heading multi-level list won't do what I want

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to set a multi-level heading list to work as follows:

```
1
  1A
    1.1
    1.2
  1B
    1.3
```

Is there a way to make Word do this rather than going back to 1.1 after 1B (for example)?

Comment: So basically, I want to make Word ignore a level in the numbering process for sub-levels, but I still want to retain its intelligence with regard to higher levels and other things on the same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with the standard headings.

What you are trying is to build a double hierarchy, where 1A, 1B, etc. is one level of grouping, and 1.1, 1.2, ... is another - completely independent - level of grouping, and then intersperse them at will. The standard heading structures of word are strictly hierarchical.

There is a relatively easy work-around: Declare a numbered format ('style')for your 1A, 1B, etc., basing its numbering on the main chapter plus a running count, and use that format/style for those lines. It will work similar to figure-numbers - the numbering is Chapter-Count, for you '1A', '1B', ... and later (in chapter 2), automatically '2A', '2B', and so on.

Unfortunately, this is rather complex, and in addition works a bit different in each Word version; here are instructions for Word 2010:

1. In the ribbon menu, chose the structured numbering button, and chose 'Define New List Style':
   [image]
2. set to 'Apply formatting to' Level 2 (because you only care for the second level of it):

[image]

3. Then, at the bottom, choose the button 'Format', and chose 'Numbering'. In the upcoming dialog, first chose the 2 in the top left (we still care only about Level 2 of the hierarchy), and then pick in the drop down 'Include Number from' = Level 1:

[image]

4. Work with all the other settings to get it to use the counters you want (A, B, C), the font, etc.. Link the level to a specific style (top right, second selection), to make it easily accessible.

When you want a header to be this numbering type, you can now simply select that style.

As said, it is a complex area, and you will need some fiddling until it does what you want. It is possible, but it takes some trial-and-error unfortunately - don't beat me, I am just the messenger...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  This looks good.  However, I can't work out how to base the new format's on the main chapter.  Would you be able to provide a few more details?

Comment: @NHall, I added instructions for Word 2010. Sorry I have none other at this time.

Comment: I'm not sure how this worked but after trying to define a new list style I seemed to have access to some options that had been greyed-out and that enabled me to change the restart after settings?  Anyway, thanks :)